# Find the value of a specific attribute in an XML file in java

Tags: java, xml

I need to just read the value of a single attribute inside an XML file using java.  The XML would look something like this:

```
<behavior name="Fred" version="2.0" ....>
```

and I just need to read out the version.  Can someone point in the direction of a resource that would show me how to do this?

Comment: This is a nice example why easy things are not always done easily. Even though most Java frameworks rely heavily on XML, the tools available for acutally dealing with XML in Java are quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a fancy library -- plain old JAXP versions of [DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) and [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) are pretty easy to read and write for this. Whatever you do, don't use a regular expression.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class GetVersion {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder().parse("file:////tmp/whatever.xml");
        String version = xpath.evaluate("//behavior/@version", doc);
        System.out.println(version);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[JAXB](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/package-summary.html) for brevity:

```
  private static String readVersion(File file) {
    @XmlRootElement class Behavior {
      @XmlAttribute String version;
    }
    return JAXB.unmarshal(file, Behavior.class).version;
  }
```

[StAX](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/package-summary.html) for efficiency:

```
  private static String readVersionEfficient(File file)
      throws XMLStreamException, IOException {
    XMLInputFactory inFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader xmlReader = inFactory
        .createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource(file));
    try {
      while (xmlReader.hasNext()) {
        if (xmlReader.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
          if (xmlReader.getLocalName().equals("behavior")) {
            return xmlReader.getAttributeValue(null, "version");
          } else {
            throw new IOException("Invalid file");
          }
        }
      }
      throw new IOException("Invalid file");
    } finally {
      xmlReader.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: That JAXB version is rather disturbing in terms of overhead. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's [one](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/org.xml.sax/extracting-attribute-values-from-xml-elements-3.html).

```
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

/**
 * Here is sample of reading attributes of a given XML element.
 */

public class SampleOfReadingAttributes {
    /**
     * Application entry point
     * @param args command-line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // creates and returns new instance of SAX-implementation:
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

            // create SAX-parser...
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            // .. define our handler:
            SaxHandler handler = new SaxHandler();

            // and parse:
            parser.parse("sample.xml", handler);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Our own implementation of SAX handler reading
     * a purchase-order data.
     */
    private static final class SaxHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        // we enter to element 'qName':
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                String qName, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {

            if (qName.equals("behavior")) {
                // get version
                String version = attrs.getValue("version");


                System.out.println("Version is " + version );

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd use this approach if I was on JSE5, but the javax.xml.stream API in Java 6 and JEE lets you quit parsing after the first element without resorting to artificial mechanisms like throwing an exception.

Comment: Boy, this is complicated. Creating a SAXParserFactory, a SAXParser, and a custom SaxHandler just to execute "//behaviour" is a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you can use the SAXParser.

Digester mentioned using regular expressions, which I won't recommend as it would lead to code that is difficult to maintain: What if you add another version attribute in another tag, or another behaviour tag? You can handle it, but it won't be pretty.

You can also use [XPath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html), which is a language for querying xml. That's what I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to read the version, then you can use regex. But really, I think you need [apache digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/commons-digester-1.8.1/docs/api/org/apache/commons/digester/package-summary.html)

Comment: XML + regext = flame bait :) But I agree with your recommendation of apache digester.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) is nice, too. Commons Digester is based on it.